# is anyone aware of LinkedIn api for blackberry java based development?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, linkedin-api

is anyone aware of LinkedIn api for blackberry java based development?
please tell me how to implement this in blackberry application

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedIn-J](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) is a Java wrapper for the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis).

Comment: It contains generics and other Java 5 stuff. This is not compilable in BB. But as I said maybe he could reuse some classes.

Comment: could you please tell me how to get access token, token secret ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a java library? I don't know if it exists for BB, but very likely it doesn't. If there's a Java API for other platform, as long as it is source compatible with Java 1.4 you can reuse some parts.

There is a REST API anyway:
http://developer.linkedin.com/rest

Comment: As long as you have HTTP in your BlackBerry, is should be!

Comment: I'm with Mister Smith here. Just use REST API via http. The only possible trouble here is that "the LinkedIn API uses OAuth as its authentication method", so you'll have to implement it or (what is better and what they recommend) you'll have to use some of existing OAuth libs - http://oauth.net/code/ . Check sources for those libs, hopefully some of them can be easily adopted to BB Java 1.3.

Comment: thank you,sorry for delay,i refer http://www.dxysolutions.com/#/does/using-interactive-oauth-on-the-blackberry but i am unable to get Token plese guide me hoe to get access token using oauth lib

Comment: I think that new doubt is worthy of posting another question.